# Getting all subviews for a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to get an array of all the subviews in a `UIScrollView`.  Right now I'm using

```
NSArray *subviews = [myScrollView subviews];
```

but this seems to only be returning the subviews that are visible at the time the code is run.  I need all the subviews in the whole extent of the UIScrollView, even those that are currently hidden (as in off screen).  How would I get that?

Essentially, I'm looking for something like the `contentSize` property of a `UIScrollView`, except instead of returning just the size of the `UIScrollView` if it were big enough to display all of it's content, I want it to return the content itself.

EDIT: I think I've figured it out: the scroll view this isn't working for is actually a `UITableView` - and I think it's deque-ing the cells that are off screen on me, and that's why they aren't showing up.  I'm going to do some testing to confirm.

Comment: That code should work. How/when are those views being added to the scroll view?

Comment: Subviews answers all subviews, visible or not.  In fact, the normal gotcha on this question is that subviews answers _too many_ subviews, including scroll indicators.  Please post the code where you think you're adding more than your getting.

Comment: Your edit is correct. As soon as a cell is offscreen, it is removed from the scrollview and placed in the reuse queue.

Comment: @CleverError: I've removed the line `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell Identifier"];` from my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because I thought that was the line that removes offscreen cells, but it doesn't seem to have helped - the cells offscreen still are not being put into my array.  How do I stop it from removing the cells when they go off-screen?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to stop a tableview from removing cells. Why do you need to get a cell that isn't visible anyway?

Comment: @CleverError: I'm essentially trying to save a "screenshot" as a .pdf, but it needs to have all the data in the table included in 1 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

It turns out that

```
NSArray *subviews = [myScrollView subviews];
```

will indeed return all the subviews in a `UIScrollView *myScrollView`, even if they are off-screen.

---

**The Details**

The problem I was actually having was that the scroll view I was trying to use this on was actually a `UITableView`, and when a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView` goes off-screen, it actually gets removed from the `UITableView` - so by the time I was calling `subviews`, the cells I was looking for were no longer in the scroll view.

My workaround was to build all of my `UITableViewCell`s in a separate method called by my `viewDidLoad`, then put all of those cells into an array.  Then, instead of using `subviews`, I just used that array.  Of course, doing it this way hurts the performance a little (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just return the cell from the array, which is slower than the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method that is typically used), but it was the only way I could find to get the behavior I needed.

Answer (score 8):

Try with following code its working for me.

```
for(UIView * subView in myScrollView.subviews ) // here write Name of you ScrollView.
{ 
     // Here You can Get all subViews of your myScrollView.
    // But For Check subview is specific UIClass such like label, button, textFiled etc.. write following code (here checking for example UILabel class).

        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) // Check is SubView Class Is UILabel class?
        {
            // You can write code here for your UILabel;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I don't think you are quite understanding what I'm asking.  I don't need any help with how to use the subviews once I've found them, I need help getting all the subviews - even if they are currently "off screen".

Comment: I just tried this and it should return all of the subviews. The subviews property is inherited from UIView and is not specific to UIScrollView. How do you know that you are not getting all of the subviews?